# Why can't I reference to PaginatedList.cs in index.cshtml.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, assembly-references

A friend and I are following this tutorial but changing things to match our project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-3.0

We have checked everything multiple times and are getting the following errors. We are having problems with referencing the PaginatedList.cs class which is in the VitekSite project. We are trying to refer to the PaginatedList.cs class from the index.cshtml.cs class.

My problem starts with the first error when I delete the following:

```
public IList<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

and replace it with the following:

```
public PaginatedList<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

The public PaginatedList can't be referred to but all my namespaces and using references are correct.

I get the following two errors. If I can fix the first one I think the second one will be solved.

> 1. Error  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'PaginatedList<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VitekSite   C:\Users\ahmad\source\repos\VitekSite\VitekSite\Pages\Customers\Index.cshtml.cs 29  Active
> 2. Error  CS0103  The name 'PaginatedList' does not exist in the current context  VitekSite   C:\Users\ahmad\source\repos\VitekSite\VitekSite\Pages\Customers\Index.cshtml.cs 72  Active

So to summarize, my problem is that I can't refer to PaginatedList in the index.cshtml.cs class.

Here is a link of the code which we have so far.

https://github.com/ahma0307/VitekSite6

UPDATE: Everything is working now but we are getting the following warnings Hmm. Everything is working but we are getting the following warnings for some reason.

> C:\Users\EAL\Source\Repos\VitekSite6\VitekSite\VitekSite.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'PagedList 1.17.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
> 1>C:\Users\EAL\Source\Repos\VitekSite6\VitekSite\VitekSite.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'PagedList.Mvc 4.5.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
> 1>VitekSite -> C:\Users\EAL\Source\Repos\VitekSite6\VitekSite\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\VitekSite.dll

Update 2: We have tried removing the ASP.NET (Classic) Reference but when we do that the site stops working [Image of error when running site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFGPN.png)

Comment: Links to code aren't as useful as posting a minimal reproducible example, particularly when that link doesn't actually include any code. Your github link points to a readme, no actual code.

Comment: I've cleaned up the question a bit but please replace the link to an empty repo with [the actual code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Comment: post your namespace lines for paginatedlist and for your .cs file... or try using PMC: Install-Package PagedList.Mvc -Version 4.5.0

Comment: @DetectivePikachu oh okay will remember that in the future. So I should delete the link and just keep the two lines of code that are giving the problem? The link is updated and contains the actual code...

Comment: Please don't reference the `PagedList` package. That's not for ASP.NET Core but for ASP.NET (classic).

Comment: Okay please just ignore this post for now..My classmate and I have run into some other problems this morning and are trying to get everything backup and running

Comment: @pccalkins Thankyou very much. we did that yesterday. For some reason it didn't work right when we did it but now when we restarted everything its working. Am not sure why. perhaps because we had to restart the pc after we used the PMC to install the package.

Comment: Update added to original problem

Comment: @CodingStudent You get the warning because you're [referencing the `PagedList` package](https://github.com/ahma0307/VitekSite6/blob/661751a7204fbaff740abf97f0479b3d155804b2/VitekSite/VitekSite.csproj#L19-L20). As I commented above, the two packages are designed for ASP.NET (Classic) instead of ASP.NET Core. Please remove these packages.

Comment: @Itiminus ooh okay thanks. Will look into removing them now..thought you meant my tag on here should be changed from ASP.NET Core to ASP.NET

Comment: @Itiminus I have put an update up in the problem. We have removed the referencing but when we do the site stops working.